# Performance issues using neo4j @QueryResult

Tags: performance, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using neo4j with spring data.
When I use queries which return multiple fields I generally try and return an interface (@QueryResult annotated), so I won't need to convert the results afterwards.


For Some reason I experience very bad performance as the number of results grow.

Does anyone have solution?


I'm using neo4j 2.0.1 through rest, spring data for neo4j 3.0.0

The dataset is very small, less than a 100 nodes, and the result set is at most ~10 records.

Answer (score 1):

Spring-Data-Neo4j-Rest is quite slow because it was built for the embedded database.

Here are fixes that can help improve the performance of your application still leveraging SDN's power to deserialize the objects for you.

1. Write your own cypher queries, and use @QueryResult more to retrieve connected nodes. DONT USE THE @Fetch annotation. SDN will make extra REST calls in an attempt to serialize the entire object graph when it could be done in a single query.

For example,

```
public class Person {

    @RelatedTo (type = "MARRIED", direction = BOTH)
    private Person partner;

}

@QueryResult
public class PersonResult {

     @ResultColumn("person")
     private Person person;

     @ResultColumn("partner")
     private Person partner;

}
```

In your repository then fetch your results

```
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository <Person> {
       @Query ("MATCH person-[m:MARRIED]-partner RETURN person, partner)
       List<PersonResult> findAllMarried ();
}
```

2. AGAIN REMOVE THOSE DEADLY @FETCH ANNOTATIONS.

Your objects are serialized in batch this way. This is very efficient pending when the SDN team work out a better way to solve this problem.